# A word for "being friendly and helpful to youngsters"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there a known word for an older adult whose ongoing desire is the welfare of young teens (as a friend but who has no interest in any type of sexual interactions) I have been a coach (of both boys and girls) for many years and it seems that following that period in my life, I really have a desire to befriend kids and act as a mentor for those who do not have comfortable situations at home.

FYI, I have been married to the same woman for 45 years and have 3 grown children but I still really enjoy being around young teens.

Comment: I changed the original title because it came off as being slightly creepy. Once I read the question that awkwardness disappeared, but still...

Answer (score 3):

There is *avuncular*.

[Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/avuncular) has:

> *Kind and friendly towards a younger or less experienced person.*

The word is related to "uncle" so tends to be used more for a male person.

Grammarphobia [lists a female version](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2006/08/female-version-of-avuncular.html), *materteral*, however this is  so rarely used as to be ineffective in general conversation.